# New web hosting breaks webcam that worked with old web hosting

Tags: javascript, ssl, webcam

I have a hobby weather website that I recently moved from HostGator web hosting to Hostinger web hosting. Everything works well at the new host with the exception of my webcam. The cam page on the website uses a script that pulls a static image from my camera, displays it, and then updates it every 1 seconds... this worked very well with the old hosting and fails with the new hosting. I'm a complete dunce when it comes to coding and don't know how to fix this issue. I do suspect however that the issue is the way SSL is forced for everything on my new host. The URL the script is pulling from my camera is: http://172.100.163.136/webcapture.jpg?command=snap&channel=1&user=viewer&password

That URL works in a browser as http but not https

Here's the script I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    var refreshrate = 1;          // seconds between refresh
    var image       = "http://172.100.163.136/webcapture.jpg?command=snap&channel=1&user=viewer&password";    // image name
    var imgwidth    = 665;        // image width
    var imgheight   = 374;        // image height
    var imgalt      = "WebCam Image";
    var imgtitle    = "header=[WebCam Image] body=[WebCam Image Automatically Updated Every 1-2 Seconds] delay=[500]";
    function refresh() { document.images["pic"].src = image + "?" + new Date(); setTimeout('refresh()', refreshrate * 500); }
    document.write('<img src="' + image + '" alt="' + imgalt + '" title="' + imgtitle + '" name="pic" id="pic" width="' + imgwidth + '" height="' + imgheight + '" style="border:1px dashed gray;"/>');
    if(document.images)window.onload=refresh;
    // ]]>
    </script>
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you update the `172.100.163.136` server to use `https`?

Comment: I wish, but no I can't update the server... it's an IP camera and not configurable for https.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution... The new host was "forcing" https with the let's encrypt SSL solution. I was able to change a setting to end forcing https but yet leave SSL intact. Webcam working again!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).